# MassTransit.PayloadNotFoundException

Tags: .net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

when i try to consume a message, i get this error in rabbitmq management:

```
MT-Fault-ExceptionType: MassTransit.PayloadNotFoundException
```

```
MT-Fault-Message:   The payload was not found: MassTransit.MessageSchedulerContext
```

```
MT-Fault-StackTrace:    at MassTransit.PipeExtensions.GetPayload[TPayload](PipeContext context) in /_/src/MassTransit.Abstractions/Middleware/PipeExtensions.cs:line 55
at MassTransit.Context.ScheduleMessageRedeliveryContext`1.ScheduleRedelivery(TimeSpan delay, Action`2 callback) in /_/src/MassTransit/Contexts/Context/ScheduleMessageRedeliveryContext.cs:line 28
at MassTransit.Middleware.RedeliveryRetryFilter`2.Send(TContext context, IPipe`1 next) in /_/src/MassTransit/Middleware/RedeliveryRetryFilter.cs:line 101
```

and here is the configuration:

```
private static void AddMessagingConfiguration(IServiceCollection services, WebApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        services.AddMassTransit(busConfigurator =>
        {
            busConfigurator.AddConsumer<GtsDocumentConsumer>();
            busConfigurator.AddEntityFrameworkOutbox<CompanyGoodsDbContext>(outboxConfigurator =>
            {
                outboxConfigurator.UseSqlServer();
                outboxConfigurator.UseBusOutbox();
                outboxConfigurator.QueryMessageLimit = 10;
                outboxConfigurator.QueryDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
                outboxConfigurator.QueryTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
            });

            busConfigurator.AddOptions<MassTransitHostOptions>()
                .Configure(options =>
                {
                    options.WaitUntilStarted = true;
                    //options.StartTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
                    //options.StopTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
                });
            

            busConfigurator.UsingRabbitMq((busContext, transportConfigurator) =>
            {
                transportConfigurator.Host(builder.Configuration["EventBusSettings:HostAddress"], "/", hostConfiguration =>
                {
                    hostConfiguration.Username(builder.Configuration["EventBusSettings:Username"]);
                    hostConfiguration.Password(builder.Configuration["EventBusSettings:Password"]);
                });

                transportConfigurator.AutoStart = true;
                transportConfigurator.UseMessageRetry(r => r.Immediate(5));
                transportConfigurator.UseScheduledRedelivery(r =>
                    r.Intervals(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)));
                transportConfigurator.ConfigureEndpoints(busContext);
            });
        });
    }
```

this configuration works fine when we are testing everything locally in docker between two applications but now when both applications runs on the server I got this error

Comment: based on my reasearch it seems there is problem with message schedule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UseScheduledRedelivery` -> `UseDelayedRedelivery`

Requires the `delayed-exchnage` plug-in on RabbitMQ.

Also, order matters, as per the [documentation](https://masstransit.io/documentation/concepts/exceptions#redelivery):

`UseDelayedRedelivery`
then
`UseMessageRetry`